# Count no of records if no. of fields are not equal to a certain variable

Tags: unix, awk

I have a csv file , i want to count no of records which doesnt have NF(no of fields) equal to a certain number ,

I have tried

```
nawk '{print NF}' FS='|' "$CSVFILE" | grep "$Variable" | nawk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

here CSVFILE is any CSV file 
and variable is any random number which user except to find if file contain that no of fields or not

is there any way i can use it only through awk

Sample input file

```
dsdgh||@jhsjdh||jdhjdhfu|123|
#45ghf|123|laiej||||
|hyrhyf|||fhyr|@#$%|
```

suppose i want to check how many records have no of fields not equlas to 5

so expected output should be 3 as all 3 record have NF smaller or greater than 5

Comment: Be careful to remember that from awk's point of view, if the field separator is `|` then the line `|hyrhyf|||fhyr|@#$%|` will have seven fields (i.e., `NF` == 7).  If by number of fields you mean non-empty fields, that's a slightly different question.

Comment: @jas |hyrhyf|||fhyr|@#$%| will have seven fields , and by NF here i mean non-empty as well as empty both ,that is irrespective of records

Answer (score 2):

Increment the count when `NF` is not equal to `n` and print the count at the end:

```
awk -F"|" -v n=5 'NF!=n{COUNT++} END{print COUNT}'   Input_file
```

Comment: OP is requesting number of line instead of lines correponding ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: I had edited ir before hek2mgl edited my post with the answer which gives the total of those lines which are not equal of number of fields provided by user etc.

Comment: The previous answer (pre-edit) was nice: it was simpler and just by pipeing into `wc` would have printed the number of lines.

Comment: @linuxfan `awk 'NF!=n'` is not a very complex statement. If you miss it, now you have it. The problem here was that non of the answers clearly said: Do this, because ... <period>! That's why I've edited this answer because I don't wanted to add another one.

Comment: @hek2mgl @neronlevelu I actually missed the "only through awk" part of the question. And yes, `NF != n` is not complex.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to your file

Assuming

- `VarNumber` is a valid integer (not part of the request to secure this)
- File(s) exists and are readeable

The commented code

```
awk -F '[|]' -v NotEqualTo="${VarNumber}" '
   # if record have number of field NOT equal to given number
   NF != NotEqualTo {
      # Count the line
      c++
      }

   # at end of file
   END {
     # print the count (only)
     print c
     }
   ' YourFile
```

Note:

- using `-F '[|]'` to avoid any missunderstanding with the RegEx OR depending option/config used
- `VarNumber` is the batch variable with your number of field that are excluded

Generic for lot of file

```
awk -F '[|]' -v NotEqualTo="${VarNumber}" '
   # Count if NF is NOT the number given and put info in array
   # 1 entry by file name
   NF != NotEqualTo {c[FILENAME]++}

   # at end of file, print the count (only) for each file (eement of array)
   END { for( f in c) print f " : " c[f] }
   ' YourFiles*
```

Comment: `awk -F'|' -v num 'NF!=num{c++}END{print c}'` would have been enough and easier to read - imo.

Comment: what is the difference , i mean on the code action ?

Comment: Pipe both commands to the `wc -c` and compare the results. That's the difference ;) On the code level, if `FS` is just a single char, fields will be delimited by that char. `FS` is not a regular expression in that case. You don't need to `[|]`. You can simply use `'|'`

Comment: I just pointed towards the number of characters you used to do a simple thing. In awk  brevity is mostly gold. Mostly, not always, of course.

Comment: i'm wrong or stackoverflow is more a site to explain code or error/problem and not providing most efficient code for itself (not a problem to do it also like you did). This was the purpose of such a long comment in my codes allowing people to understand and adapt belong their needs.

Comment: PS: Another thing. Please quote `${VarNumber}` since just because it is named `VarNumber` that does not guarantee that it will always contain a number.

Comment: Please explain the value of the comment `# Count if NF is NOT the number given` in front of `NF != NotEqualTo {c++}`. (for example) I know I'm pedantic now but you asked for that. ;) A comment like "`NF` holds the number of fields in the record, please refer to ..." might have added value, sure.

Comment: fair, adapted comment on reply to be a bit more exhaustif

Answer (score 1):

this will give you the full distribution of number of fields

```
$ awk -F\| '{c[NF]++} END{for(i in c) print i ":", c[i]}' file | sort
```

to recover all but equal to 5, pipe to another `awk`

```
$ ... |  awk '!/^5:/{sum+=$2} END{print sum}'
```